# Discussion: Should CDC based producer tests mock business logic or integrate with business logic

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

My question addresses a conceptual issue with consumer driven contracts (CDCs), not with Spring-Cloud-Contract in particular (though tagged otherwise).

A CDC usually *guarantees* a particular behavior of a service (producer/supplier) to its client (consumer). Many architectures (e.g. Hexagonal/Clean/Onion Architecture) have an adapter/layer to provide the technical interface(s) of the service (REST/SOAP/Messaging/...). They separate the adapter from the business logic. When tests are written based on a CDC it is possible to just test the adapter (classical unit test) and mock away the business logic.

However, the contract formally does not only specify a particular mapping of the result (from the business logic) to the data transfer object as returned by the adapter. Moreover it contains semantics wrt. to the request/response behavior: If the consumer sends a specific request with meaningful data, the producer should respond with a particular *correct* answer (with respect to the request).

**My point for discussion/question is**: Should the test on the producer side then be an integration test (integrating business logic) to check if the business logic will return the correct answer? In this case the next layer (behind business logic) might be mocked away as long as the business logic is an integral part of the test case.

In Spring CDCs (but I think in other CDC implementations as well) it is possible to distinguish between consumer and producer side and the generated test cases. For example it would be possible to reduce the producer part to check for formal correctness of the response (e.g., if a particular data item is contained and validates against a pattern) while it specifies a concrete response for the consumer part at the same time. This might lead to the (mis-) understanding on the consumer side (and backed by the consumer tests) that the concrete specified data would be returned by the producer if the consumer had sent the specified request from the CDC.

What do users of CDCs think? How do you specify behavior and to what extent do you test it on the producer side?

Comment: I had the same question after implementing the cloud contracts in source code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883754/what-are-we-actually-testing-using-spring-cloud-contracts..If there's a possibility of discrepancy between the underlying business logic and the contracts, I don't see how else can the cloud contracts be useful

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept of contract tests @sns879. Those tests are not to replace business logic tests, they're to assert semantic compatibility. If you want to go through the whole business flow then you should be doing end to end tests. However if you can't pass contract tests for sure you won't pass end to end (running those is more costly). You can check one of my talks where I explain that in more details https://toomuchcoding.com/talks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We describe it in the documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-introducing-spring-cloud-contract-purposes . Let me write it here for your convenience

> Spring Cloud Contract’s purpose is NOT to start writing business
> features in the contracts. Assume that we have a business use case of
> fraud check. If a user can be a fraud for 100 different reasons, we
> would assume that you would create two contracts, one for the positive
> case and one for the negative case. Contract tests are used to test
> contracts between applications and not to simulate full behavior.

If you check Pact's documentation (https://docs.pact.io/faq#do-i-still-need-end-to-end-tests) you'll find

> Contract tests replace a certain class of system integration test (the
> ones you do to make sure that you're using the API correctly and that
> the API responds the way you expect). They don't replace the tests
> that ensure that the core business logic of your services is working.

In case of Spring Cloud Contract - if you have a controller that delegates work to a service, then you should mock out the service and test only whether your controller can take a request and send back a proper response